# Android Compile Time directive

Tags: android, build

I have an android application with different flavours.What I mean by flavours is that they differ only in their application name,icon and a url that webview in the application uses.

What I have now:
Application 1 with app_name1 and icon1:
{
Code...
myWebview.loadUrl(url1);
code..
}
Application 2 with app_name2 and icon2:
{
SameCode...
myWebview.loadUrl(url2)
Samecode..
}

What I would like to have :

Application(pick the application name and icon from build parameter):
{
Code ..
myWebview.loadUrl(pick the url from build parameter)
Code..
}

Is this possible? 
This would be so good to have as I am manually copying any change that i do in either of the projects to the other and I am scared about how I would handle more than 2 "flavours".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).  See for instance [this blog post](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-library-projects.html):

> Library Projects allow you to share some whole parts of your applications, resources included. 
>   The main and immediate use is to create several versions of the same application.

Comment: Looks like what i have in mind. Will check them out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should in any case be using resources to refer to these things.  So e.g

```
<application android:label="@string:app_name" android:icon="@drawable:icon">
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and

```
String rl = getString(R.string.url);
```

in your code.

Then you simply have to swap in the right `res/values/strings.xml` and `res/drawable/icon.png`, and change the name of your final apk.